# Inserting foreign key value inSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If i have two table, EMPLOYEE and DEPARTMENT, of form:
for DEPARTMENT: **dno   dname   dlocation   emgr**
for EMPLOYEE:   **eno ename ejob emgr ehiredate esalary commission edno**
where The primary key of EMPLOYEE is eno and that of DEPARTMENT is dno. There are two foreign keys:
EMPLOYEE.edno that references DEPARTMENT and EMPLOYEE.emgr that references EMPLOYEE. The
EMPLOYEE.emgr holds eno of the manager for an employee.
I want to insert values in DEPARTMENT:

```
(10, ’Accounting’, ’New York’);
(20, ’Research’, ’Dallas’);
(30, ’Sales’, ’Chicago’);
(40, ’Operations’, ’Boston’);
```

How to do I add the value of emgr in the DEPARTMENT table since it is a foreign key from employee?

Comment: What values do you want to add?

Comment: I think you should edit your question by adding the table creation syntax that you used. Then  you do not need to describe the schema in words and it will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

One solution couöld be

1. In the Department table allow NULL for  emgr
2. INSERT A new DEPARTMENT with NULL for emgr
3. -WHen you enter a new employee or change one, a AFTER upDATE TRIPPER and AFTET INSERT TRIGGeR  will update the Department with the emgr.

additional i would also run once a day an event which will check if there are DEPARTMENTS that have emgr IS NULL and get the information for employee , as long as there is at least one that has a emgr and a dpno that fits